# Consider a set A = {0,1,2,3}, a relation R from set A = {(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}. Is relation R transitive? If yes, how?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

I was told relation R is transitive but for it to be transitive, (a,b) and (b,c) must belong to R, and only then if (a,c) belongs to R, it is transitive, so how is it transitive?

---

Comment: If $p\longrightarrow q$ and $p$ is `false` then the whole story is valid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Nothing vacuous about it. At no point in the definition of transitive does it say that the three elements have to be distinct.

Comment: Yep, it seems like a Vacuous Truth situation.  I think if there are simply no conditions in the relation to check if the relation is transitive or not, then it is transitive. In the question, there was no (a,b) and neither (b,c) hence there were no conditions to check (a,c) whether it belonged to R or not, hence it seems to be transitive

Comment: @Arthur, thanks. I understood that; I think I just confused myself on the definition of vacuously true though!

Comment: @AryanRaveshia It is not vacuous since you have to check the case a=b=c.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a,b,c\in A$
we will show $aRb$ and $bRc \implies aRc$
$a=b=c$
$a=c$
$aRc$
so R is transitive.

the subset of $A\times A$ for which the relation $R$ holds is the diagonal of $A\times A$.

Answer (score 0):

To give a slightly different perspective on this, a relationship is an equivalence relation iff it is transitive, reflexive, and symmetric. The relationship that $R$ describes is good old fashioned honest to goodness equality, which should be an equivalence relationship if anything is. Because equality should be an equivalence relation, it should be transitive.

Of course, this is all motivation and insight, an actual proof of the fact that $R$ is transitive must go as other users suggest.